# Выдает ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught Error

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in 
C:\OSPanel\domains\dblog\admin\includes\connection.php:4 Stack trace: #0 
C:\OSPanel\domains\dblog\admin\includes\header.php(4): require_once() #1 
C:\OSPanel\domains\dblog\admin\register.php(1): include('C:\\OSPanel\\doma...') #2 {main} thrown in 
C:\OSPanel\domains\dblog\admin\includes\connection.php on line 4
```

Вод код с той строки

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() - в переводе __Вызов неопределенной функции mysql_connect()__ . Версия php у вас какая?

Comment: http://be2.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php
Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan спасибо, но теперь выдает другую ошибку Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\OSPanel\domains\dblog\admin\includes\connection.php on line 5
Cannot select DB

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan хотя подключение верное указал

Comment: `mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");  ` заменить на свои значения и будет вам счастье

Comment: `$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER, DB_PASS, 'Имя базы') or die(mysqli_connect_error());` 4-тым параметром надо указать имя базы

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Все отлично работает, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, ошибка была из за старой версии php код, так как на моем сервере 7.2

Вот правильный код

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME') or 
die(mysqli_connect_error());
```